# How to create/define concentration risk limits for credit portfolios

Tags: credit-risk

How do you create/define concentration risk limits for credit portfolios?

I've seen a lot of recommendation for HHI for example, but how do I define what is high or low concentration?

The idea of the analysis is not regulatory but for my own control of the portfolio positions and credit risk distribution. The portfolio is composed of basically retail credits.

Are there better alternatives to HHI?

**Edit**: Pleb commented on $HHI_t = \sum_{i=1}^d(w_t^i)^2$ where $HHI_t \in [\frac{1}{d}, 1]$, because if I have a single exposition then I have maximum value and if I have expositions with equal weights, then $HHI_t = \sum_{i=1}^d(\frac{1}{d})^2 = d\frac{1}{d^2} = \frac{1}{d}$. We could normalize it to be $HHI_t \in [0, 1]$ by subtracting $\frac{1}{d}$ on the nominator and denominator, then $cHHI_t = \frac{HHI_t - \frac{1}{d}}{1- \frac{1}{d}}$. But then, how further from  0 is a worrying point? How high should be my HHI before I start to worry and notice I have a concentration problem?
Let's say I have to redistribute my expositions somehow if I hit a certain value. How do I define that value? Is there a metric in which that value is easier to define?

Its intuitive to think its highly correlated with my risk apetite. But how do I use that to obtain a concentration limit?

**Edit2:** Also from Pleb: Together with industry experts (or by yourself) its possible to scout which portfolio would seem concentrated (simply by altering the weights). That way, you go through different allocations in order to pinpoint the portfolios that seem concentrated. Then, calculate the cHHIt metric for the portfolios that are deemed concentrated. The point of reference can then be the average of all cHHIt, or more conservative, the smallest cHHIt and define the threshold there.

Comment: Is this not described in the applicable regulations? What is the goal of this? Regulatory compliance or your own analysis?

Comment: It's my own analysis. The motivation is to check the portfolio positions and credit risk distribution to see if it's too concentrated in a certain rating/region. As it's basically a retail portfolio there is no name concentration

Comment: I reopened this question now because I do think with the added information is interesting.

Comment: *"[...] but how do I define what is high or low concentration?"*, If your portfolio can be described based on a vector of weights $(w_t^1,\ldots,w_t^d)$, then the HHI is defined as $HHI_t = \sum_{i=1}^d (w_t^i)^2$ and has support $HHI_t \in [\frac{1}{d}, 1]$. That is, the HHI-metric imply that the equally weighted portfolio has the smallest asset concentration possible. From this, we can then further correct the HHI measure, such that it is bounded between 0 and 1: $cHHI_t = 1 - \frac{1-HHI_t}{1-\frac{1}{d}}$. If the $cHHI_t$ is close to 0, the concentration is low and vice-versa for 1.

Comment: The $cHHI_t$ metric might help with the intuition on portfolio concentration, so I thought it would be decent information to share.

Comment: Thank you Pleb. I added your comment to my question because I think it helps not only with the answer but with people understanding it. But how further from 0 is a worrying point? Let's say I have to redistribute my expositions somehow if I hit a certain value. How do I define that value?

Comment: @IdlerGhost I would establish a point of reference: Together with industry experts (or just yourself) you scout which portfolio would seem concentrated (simply by altering the weights). That way, you and your team of experts go through different allocations in order to pinpoint the portfolios that seem concentrated. Then, calculate the $cHHI_t$ metric for the portfolios that are deemed concentrated. The point of reference can then be the average of all $cHHI_t$, or more conservative, the smallest $cHHI_t$ and define the threshold there.

Comment: Any portfolio with a concentration below the point of reference, is deemed not concentrated and vice-versa for those above. This would be one solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks again Pleb. I added the answer to the question in case its helpful for someone else, so they don't have to search through the comments. It seems like solid process. However, is there a more objective solution (not necessarily cHHI)? Because I understand that the answer is plausible but subjective and more prone to be criticized by units who have triggered their limit.